# Array sort by key having multilevel numbers (1.1.2 , 2.1.3 ...)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to dynamically compose an array having keys like:

> 1.1.2
>   2.1.3
>   2.1.13

After composing I need to order data by key but I get a result different from needed:

```
$Vals=array("1.1.2"=>"First","2.1.3"=>"Second","2.1.13"=>"Third");
ksort($Vals);

foreach($Vals as $x=>$x_value)
   {
   echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
   echo "<br>";
   }
```

I get:

> Key=1.1.2, Value=First
>   Key=2.1.13, Value=Third
>   Key=2.1.3, Value=Second

instead of

> Key=1.1.2, Value=First
>   Key=2.1.3, Value=Second
>   Key=2.1.13, Value=Third

Comment: You should mention that your "multilevel numbers" are actually version numbers or so it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing simple lexicographical comparison, but what you're trying to compare are version number identifiers, which have their own logic. PHP has a function to compare such standardised version number strings: [`version_compare`](http://php.net/version_compare).

```
uksort($Vals, 'version_compare');
```